# Proving Cantor's theorem for powersets except one element of them?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can one prove the following:

$\forall x: \operatorname {inf}(x) \to \forall y \, ( y \subseteq x \to |\mathcal P(x) \setminus \{y\}| \neq |x|)$?

Where $\operatorname {inf}$ means "is infinite set".

in $\sf Z$ and $\sf ZC$?

In English: the cardinality of the set of all subsets of a set except one, is not equal to the cardinality of that set.

Comment: consider a set of 0 or 1 elements

Comment: @BenjaminWang, I don't know what  you are hinting at?

Comment: Let $n=|x|$, so $|\mathcal{P}(x)|=2^n$. Then $n=0\implies 2^n=1=n+1$. Also if $n=1$ then $2^n=n+1$. So these are counterexamples to your claim. By the way I didn't downvote. You can probably fix your claim by introducing quantifiers that restrict $n\ge 2$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Ah! I see, thanks! I meant the statement to be about infinite sets. Thanks for the correction. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither replacement nor choice play a role here; a quick modification to Cantor's standard argument goes through for the stronger result where $A$ is merely assumed to have at least two elements.

Reasoning in $\mathsf{Z}$, suppose $A$ has at least two elements and $f$ is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ (it doesn't matter which set we throw out). Let $$D=\{a\in A: a\not\in f(a)\}$$ as usual. Since $A$ has at least two elements, not every nonempty subset of $A$ is a singleton, so there must be some $a_1\in A$ such that $f(a_1)\not=\{a_1\}$. By surjectivity of $f$, though, some other $a_2\in A$ has $f(a_2)=\{a_1\}$. This means that $D$ is nonempty so we get a contradiction in the usual manner.

*(As usual, this can be restructured to avoid proof by contradiction, but meh.)*

Comment: This proof is limited to when $y=\emptyset$
, I need to generalize this proof to apply to any subset $y$ of $x$. What I mean, I need a similar proof that ***DIRECTLY*** works for any subset $y$ and not just the empty set.

Comment: @Zuhair Given $u\subseteq A$, just apply the obvious bijection between $\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus \{u\}$. A bijection between $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{u\}$ automatically gives rise to a bijection between $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, so we can focus on this particular form for simplicity.

Comment: I know this argument, I don't want that. I need it to be from ground level as the argument for the empty set of yours. I think it can be done, I think we need to concentrate on the membership of $y$ or what is not an element of $y$ something like that.

Comment: @Zuhair Then **that sort of stringent requirement should be in your actual question**. I've given you a proof in $\mathsf{Z}$, or indeed much less, of the fact you asked for. That's what your question as written asked for.